# Why am I getting a segmentation error while reading integers into an array in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int length;
    printf("Enter length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    int nums[length];
    printf("Enter %d integers to be sorted: ",length);
    do{ 
        scanf("%d",&nums[i]);
        i++;
        
    }
    while (i<length);
    /* implement bubble sort*/
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<length-i-1;j++){
            if (nums[j]>nums[j+1]){
                int temp=nums[j];
                nums[j]=nums[j+1];
                nums[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        printf("%d ",nums[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

The program above takes input from stdinput in the form of entering a length and then it asks stdinput for a list of integers for ex "1 2 9 4 3". However, after I finish reading the values into the array I get a segmentation error. Now I know this means that I'm accessing memory that I shouldn't be, but I'm unsure where this is occurring.

Comment: `int j=0;i<length-i-1`looks odd. Did you mean `j<length-i-1;`?

Comment: Just as a side note: Before you use the value that you assume `scanf` wrote to, you should check the return value of `scanf` to ensure that it actually wrote to that value.

Comment: `i` never changes in `for(int j=0;i<length-i-1;j++){` so it keeps going.. and going... and going... Also a `-Wshadow` as a compiler option, your loop shadows a prior declaration of `i`. Just remove the `int` from, e.g. `for (i=0;i<length;i++)` to resolve the shadowed variable issue. Your code sorts fine after you fix those issue.

Comment: You should also add a `putchar ('\n');` before `return 0;` so your program is POSIX compliant outputting a final `'\n'`. This ensures you don't mess up the command line prompt and have it start 1/2 way across the screen after your sorted output. Lastly, you cannot use any input function correctly without ***checking the return***. What happens if `'r'` is accidentally entered instead of `4`? So `if (scanf("%d",&length) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }`

Comment: Thank you guys so much! That was a huge help. @AndreasWenzel I will add that.

Comment: Yes @UnholySheep thank you for catching that

Comment: Also, improving spacing will make your code more readable -- especially for older eyes, e.g. [Your Code Improved Spacing](https://paste.opensuse.org/6569975)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int length;
    printf("Enter length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    int* p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    
    printf("Enter %d integers to be sorted: ", length);
    do {
        scanf("%d", p + i);
        i++;

    } while (i < length);
    /* implement bubble sort*/
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
            if (p[j] > p[j + 1]) {
                int temp = p[j];
                p[j] = p[j + 1];
                p[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    }
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I have changed yours. Hope you can understand it.

Comment: Good effort, but you cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return***.